# Sterric after every letter but not after last letter in python

Tags: python

How to write a function called betterStarify(inputString) that takes in a string, and returns a new string with a *after each letter in the original string, but not after the last letter in the string.

the Program output should be

```
print betterStarify('OMG') ==> O*M*G 
print betterStarify('wicked') ==> w*i*c*k*e*d
print betterStarify('Starry') ==> S*t*a*r*r*y
```

Comment: Looks like homework, what have you tried?

Comment: I'll give you a hint for your homework, first look into how to split it... perhaps using for loop and then using string join on the result.

Comment: thank you i have solved it now bymyself

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
def betterStarify(x):
    return '*'.join(x)
```